# How to manually re-render component using react-hook-form when validation errors are updated

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form, flatpickr

facing challenges making validation classes to reflect automatically on custom datepicker Flatpickr using React-Hook-Forms,

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm({
  mode: 'onChange'
})

<FormGroup>
  <Controller
    name="dateControl"
    control={control}
    defaultValue={null}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    render={({ value, onChange }) => (
      <Flatpickr
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        id="hf-picker"
        options={{
          altInput: true,
          altFormat: 'F j, Y',
          dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
          altInputClass: classnames(
            'form-control flatpickr-input',
            {
              'is-invalid': errors.dateControl && true
            }
          )
        }}
      />
    )}
  />
</FormGroup>
```

After troubleshooting, I realize everything works except that component fails to re-render whenever the validation errors are updated by react-hooks-form, is there anyway I can force a manual re-render instead, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has nothing to do with RHF, but somehow the `options` prop of the `<Flatpickr />` component isn't updated when the config changes.

I'm assuming your using the `react-flatpickr` package - what you could do is simply pass the `key` prop to this component and setting it to the errors object of that control. This will force a re-render every time the errors of that form control change.

```js
const isNotEmpty = (array) => array?.length > 0 || "Required";
```

```js
<Controller
  name="dateControl"
  control={control}
  defaultValue={null}
  rules={{ validate: isNotEmpty }}
  render={({ value, onChange }) => (
    <>
      <Flatpickr
        key={errors.dateControl}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        id="hf-picker"
        options={{
          altInput: true,
          altFormat: "F j, Y",
          dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
          altInputClass: classnames("form-control flatpickr-input", {
            "is-invalid": !!errors.dateControl
          })
        }}
      />
      {errors.dateControl && <p>{errors.dateControl.message}</p>}
    </>
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

Comment: Thanks @knoefel, answer accepted but do you have any idea why it works only on first page load e.g.
1-when data is empty, it shows validation error
2-when data is supplied, it hides validation error
3-but when data is emptied, it does not show validation but still proceeds to submit with empty value

Comment: This is happening because you set the `defaultValue` prop to `null` but after selecting a date and removing it afterwards `<Flatpickr />` will set the value to an empty array. I'm not that familiar with `flatpickr` but you could just use RHF's `validate` function and check if the value is not an empty array instead of the `required` validation. I updated my answer and the CodeSandbox.